# Druid Apache Kafka setup

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I have created an AWS EC2 instance and installed druid in it. Also we are having AWS kafka running in EC2. How can I ingest data in my  kafka topic to druid?

Comment: Can you share your Druid configs? And what issues you are having [following the docs](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html)?

Comment: I have created a topic in my kafka and set values of bootstrap servers and topic in supervisor json. Now when i'm publishing event from kafka it is not receiving by druid. Is there any way to check whether the data im sending from kafka is receiving by druid?

Comment: I am personally not familiar with Druid, but log would be a start... You can also check the Kafka Consumer groups (if any are made)